# OpenSSL - Store public or private key in EVP_PKEY

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm trying to store a private key in an `EVP_PKEY` but I'm getting an error when calling the OpenSSL function `EVP_PKEY_fromdata()`.

deps:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/param_build.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * Fixed data to represent the private key.
 */
const unsigned char priv_data[] = {
    0xb9, 0x2f, 0x3c, 0xe6, 0x2f, 0xfb, 0x45, 0x68,
    0x39, 0x96, 0xf0, 0x2a, 0xaf, 0x6c, 0xda, 0xf2,
    0x89, 0x8a, 0x27, 0xbf, 0x39, 0x9b, 0x7e, 0x54,
    0x21, 0xc2, 0xa1, 0xe5, 0x36, 0x12, 0x48, 0x5d};

void errMsg(string msg)
{
    cout << msg << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
    EVP_PKEY *key = NULL;
    OSSL_PARAM_BLD *param_bld;
    OSSL_PARAM *params = NULL;

    param_bld = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_new();
    if (param_bld == NULL && OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_utf8_string(param_bld, "group", "prime256v1", 0) != 1)
    {
        errMsg("Setup params failed");
    }

    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "EC", NULL); // EC_KEY
    if (ctx == NULL || EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(ctx) <= 0)
    {
        errMsg("Setup ctx failed");
    }

    // store private key
    BIGNUM *priv = BN_bin2bn(priv_data, sizeof(priv_data), NULL);
    if (priv == NULL)
    {
        errMsg("Conversion to BIGNUM failed");
    }

    if (OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_BN(param_bld, "priv", priv) != 1)
    {
        errMsg("Loading private key data to params failed");
    }

    params = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_to_param(param_bld);

    // The returned EVP_PKEY has a private key inside
    if (EVP_PKEY_fromdata(ctx, &key, EVP_PKEY_KEY_PARAMETERS | OSSL_KEYMGMT_SELECT_PRIVATE_KEY, params) <= 0)
    {
        errMsg("Setting private key failed");
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Private key is stored inside the EVP_PKEY";
    }

    BN_free(priv);

    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
    OSSL_PARAM_free(params);
    OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(param_bld);
    return 0;
}
```

So I'm getting the error message "Setting private key failed" because the function `EVP_PKEY_fromdata()` is for some reason returning 0. I don't understand the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is an error at least in this code:

```
param_bld = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_new();
if (param_bld == NULL && OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_utf8_string(param_bld, "group", "prime256v1", 0) != 1)
{
    errMsg("Setup params failed");
}
```

It does not call `OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_utf8_string()` when `OSSL_PARAM_BLD_new()` success. Because the left condition of `&&` is false, there is no need to evaluate right condition.

There is related example in [this man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/EVP_PKEY_fromdata.3ssl.en), that even use the same private key. It may help you with your code.